# change third column in a dataframe adding a zero

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` with 2 columns that look like this:

```
>df
27-01-1345  27-01-1345
      <NA>    1-01-325
54-01-1265  54-01-1265
```

I would like to add a zero to the third group of numbers in the second column when this group of numbers has only three digits. The desired output should be the following:

```
>df
27-01-1345  27-01-1345
      <NA>    1-01-325
54-01-1265  54-01-1265
```

I know how to do it with bash scripting but I need to do it inside R

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we need to format the "325" in the second column say "V2" of dataset "df" to "0325", then use `sub`.  In the `pattern`, we can match a `-` followed by 3 characters to the end of the string (`$`).  This can be placed in a capture group (i.e. inside brackets).  The `replacement` part will have `-0` and the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`).

```
df$V2 <- sub("-(.{3})$", "-0\\1", df$V2)
df$V2
#[1] "27-01-1345" "1-01-0325"  "54-01-1265"
```